# How can I get more information about "Waiting for target device to come online" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I run Android Studio 2.3 on Ubuntu 16.10 without any devices attached. When selecting Run > Run 'app' to run the app inside an emulated device, I get to see the following notification but the target device never comes online.

[image]

If I run `adb devices` in the terminal, I get to see this:

[image]

My version of Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Use `adb devices` in the terminal

Comment: Thank you! Can you please see my edits?

Comment: Alright, so you have no devices attached? Are you using a phone, emulator, or just starting Android Studio, and it freezes?

Comment: Exactly. No device attached. I try to run it inside an emulated device.

Comment: If the emulator is up and running, `adb devices` should show something. The fact that it doesn't is why you get the progress bar. I'm not sure how you'd address it other than restarting a few times or plugging in a physical device

Comment: All of this didn't help. I will try to reinstall Android Studio.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had the same problem this morning, same version on ubuntu and android studio, 2 ways i did which helped me, i recon the second method :

1. Under the Android Virtual Device Manager, you can edit the configuration on the virtual device, fine the Emulated Performance, Set it to -> Software.
   (Bare in mind that this will make your emulator seems running slow while emulating any app).
2. Second way is to locate lib64 folder since i am running ubuntu 64 bit. In my case, its located under ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64. Then run the following commands in terminal :

//Double Check to see if these are available

$ sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386

$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

//Navigate to the ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64 folder

$ mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak

$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++

Comment: Awesome tips! Thanks :)

Comment: The last two lines fixed it for me (mv  libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak &&  ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++) although I'm working on Ubuntu, so the lib name was actually /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with just modifying a configuration on AVD.

1) Go to the AVD Manager

2) Click "Edit this AVD" Button which seems like pencil.

3) Set the graphics as a software.

Comment: I'm unable to change the setting, it defaults to automatic and is greyed out, how do I change it?

Comment: After trying all possible options like the cold boot, and wipe data, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution showed above:
//Double Check to see if these are available

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386

$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

//Navigate to the ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64 folder

```
$ mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak

$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++
```

Should work for this errors:

> libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>  libGL error:
>   driver pointer missing
>  libGL error: failed to load driver:
>   i965
>  libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>  libGL
>   error: driver pointer missing
>  libGL error: failed to load driver:
>   i965
>  libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>  libGL
>   error: failed to load driver: swrast
>  X Error of failed request: 
>   GLXBadContext
>      Major opcode of failed
>   request:  155 (GLX)
>      Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
>      Serial number
>   of failed request:  55
>      Current serial
>   number in output stream:  54

Comment: How is your answer different from the above one?

Comment: There is no difference in it. I just tried to tell that one solution also applies to another error.

Comment: Maybe we can improve the existing answer above with your information?